# Openoffice.org: Mouse wheel one row at a time possible?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-excel, openoffice

I noticed this in Excel, now in OpenOffice.org calc. One small change in mouse wheel leads to 3 rows (line) change. Is it possible to change in Calc OR/AND in Excel?

EDIT: Yes, I know about system wide setting about the number of lines for one notch of scroll. But in some applications this setting is interpreted related to size in pixels so scrolling is predictable, but for some like spreadsheet is not. Since the height of line in a cell differ depending of the cell content, with other setting as 1 you will have a guarantee of unpredictable content before your eyes with only one notch.

Comment: An old question, but it's a very good one, and I've uprated it, starred it, and added a bounty. This definitely needs a good answer. Thankyou for asking. Btw, this happens in other editors, not just Excel.

Answer (score 4):

**Control Panel** > **Mouse** > **Wheel**

[image]

Set the value for **The following number of lines at a time** to **1** and **Apply**.

Comment: Thanks, I see, but the problem is I would like it to be more responsive in the browser in this case. This setting makes sense if the "lines" in different applications mean the same. Its not the case if we compare Calc and FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by your system-wide mouse settings. You can change it there.

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be the wonderful and free [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) :

> You are able to provide application or window specific mappings, which
>   means an application or window can use the mouse buttons differently
>   from another. For each profile you can optionally define up to 5
>   'layers' of different button configurations which you can switch
>   between using hotkeys or mouse buttons.

I am a happy user of this product and in my experience it is absolutely problem-free.

If you have any other mouse software installed such as Setpoint or IntelliPoint,
they should be uninstalled because of a possible conflict with X-Mouse Button Control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer on the Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/adjust-scroll-size-of-mouse-scroll-wheel-in-excel/64635bdf-87ee-4666-ab7b-4d454bae9e82?msgId=5bb47d95-67ac-4d54-8848-4c429f61d3bd).

> There is no option/setting to control the mouse scroll speed in Excel.
>   You may refer the KB article mentioned below ‘Resolve problems with
>   mouse button or scrolling settings’ and check if it helps.
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303091